# Past Routine sentence construction

Tags: sentence-construction

Which is the correct way to construct sentence to tell past routine?

1. He slept most of time whenever I visited him.
2. He would sleep most of the time when I visited him

Comment: Yes James ... I have corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences have give the same, or similar meanings.  Using "would" to describe past routine is quite formal, and can be ambiguous with the use of "would" to form conditional expressions.

There is also "used to"

> He used to sleep for most of the time whenever I visited him.

Comment: He slept most of the time (whenever?) I visited him. He was asleep most of the time I visited him. Do you think 'used to' and/or 'would'  is OK with a verb like 'sleep'? I doubt.

Comment: Ram can u share some link or write up why we can't use this with used to or would ?

Answer (score 0):

Both are technically sound, but since it is shorter I would choose: He slept most of the time whenever I visited him.

Neither are particularly great. I would it as: “He would sleep most of the time during my visits.”

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine.

We can also say, He **used to** sleep most of the time when I visited him. (We can put 'used to' in place of 'would'. We use 'used to' to talk about past habits.)